# WPF Secondary window snapshots main window

Tags: c#, wpf

An WPF project has a MainWindow holding multiple books (in this case just one).

[image: MainWindow]

The pencil icon is in fact a button creating a new instance of the BookEdit window and showing it. Clicking it should show the following (and it used to do so).

[image: BookEdit]

My issue is that recently, the secondary window starts snapshotting the mainwindow and showing a portion of it as part of the window:

[image: Snapshot]

and it keeps doing so even when I move the window:

[image: Snapshot conservation]

Why does that happen? Is it an issue with my GPU/whatever? I cannot currently test the software on another device.

I also removed any ZIndex from the solution.

Edit 1:

It should be noted that the books from MainWindow are generated behind using Children.Add

```
Button newbutt = new Button();
                newbutt.Background = null;
                newbutt.SetResourceReference(Control.StyleProperty, "BookToolbarButton");
                newbutt.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(FileHandler.editBook);
                Image pencil = new Image();
                pencil.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/pencil.png"));
                newbutt.Content = pencil;
                sp.Children.Add(newbutt);
```

editBook():

```
string name = (((sender as Button).Parent as StackPanel).Parent as Grid).Name;
        if (System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) Console.WriteLine("Error: The book does not hold a ");
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Editting book {0}", name);
            BookEdit bEdit = new BookEdit("books/" + name + ".json");
            bEdit.Show();
        }
```

Comment: can you show us some code pls ?

Comment: have you tried using `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()` does this change anything ?

Comment: You should give us a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We are not in your pc, so we cannot guess what is happening

Comment: @Pikoh the main reason I didn't show any code yet is because I thought someone could identify this as a GPU problem. Editing to show some code behind.